# Is it possible to have multiple filevault2-activated partitions on one disk?

Tags: bootcamp, filevault, encryption, dual-boot, core-storage

What I would like to have: A disk with the following systems on it:

1. OS X 10.8 (FV2-encrypted)
2. OS X 10.9 (FV2-encrypted)
3. Windows 7

When I try to start FV2-encryption on my secondary partition, OS X tells me that in some configurations FV2 cannot be activated. Do you know if this can be done? How?

Bonus question: The Bootcamp partition is not available in the boot menu after installing 10.9. Is it possible to have multiple OS X + Bootcamp live together on one disk?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you created the second partition? I created mine by 1st) shrinking the existing FileVault 2 encrypted CoreStorage volume using "diskutil cs resizeVolume ..." and 2nd) creating a new and unencrypted CoreStorage volume using "diskutil cs createVolume ...". However, the system always boots the original FV2 encrypted volume although I select the second volume for boot in Startup manager.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like probably not, based on a few search results :(

http://macs.about.com/od/LionTipsNtricks/ss/Filevault-2-Using-Disk-Encryption-With-Os-X-Lion.htm says:

> FileVault 2 [...] only encrypts the startup drive. If you have
>   additional drives or partitions, including a Windows partition created
>   with Boot Camp, they will remain unencrypted.

This thread, however, is a bit encouraging: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5644065

On page 2, someone links to https://github.com/jridgewell/unlock which might be useful. That is, you might be able to set up a pre-login step to unlock additional volumes.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer misses the point. The first article is too generic and the Apple discussion is about two separate disks.